# Can't get EF7 (Entity Framework 7 Beta-7) to return data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

I have EF7 setup and compiling with no errors, and I can tell it is sending the SELECT command to the server, but the returning data is always null.

I am not using DI, only setting up EF in code.

Context:

```
public class ApContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FirmHdr> FirmHdr { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=azuresql.database.windows.net;Database=psAP;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class FirmHdr
{
    [Key]
    public Guid GID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public string FirmCode { get; set; }
    public string FirmName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseAmt { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string FirmAdmin { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Get Method:

```
public class ioEF7
{
    public List<FirmHdr> GetFirms()
    {
        using (var db = new ApContext())
        {
            var firms = from fx in db.FirmHdr orderby fx.FirmName select fx; //db.FirmHdr.ToList();
            var lfirms = firms.ToList();
            return lfirms;
        }

    }
}
```

No matter what I try, **firms** is always null. Any help would be appreciated!

Trace from SQL Server:

```
    SELECT [fx].[GID], [fx].[Address1], [fx].[Address2], [fx].[AdminPassword], [fx].[BaseAmt], [fx].[City], [fx].[Contact], [fx].[DateModified], [fx].[DateStart], [fx].[FirmAdmin], [fx].[FirmCode], [fx].[FirmName], [fx].[Phone], [fx].[State], [fx].[Zip], [fx].[eMail]
    FROM [FirmHdr] AS [fx]
    ORDER BY [fx].[FirmName]
```

Data returned in SQL Manager:

```
    7e699f55-167e-41d8-b4d8-97d0ebd44da9    NULL    NULL    SOBHOST NULL    NULL    THIS IS A SPECIAL ACCOUNT ONLY FOR HOST ADMINS  2014-11-02 13:25:46 2014-11-02  SOB 0HOST   HOST SETUP ACCOUNT  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    a96af7a2-5cf2-47f2-863c-7dc43bdd6a6a    NULL    NULL    NULL    100.0000    NULL    NULL    2014-11-20 21:40:51 2014-11-20  NULL    JOHNS   JOHNS FIRM  PHONE   NULL    NULL    NULL
    0094823d-ec85-4259-a094-3162673dcfd9    123 MAIN STREET STE 100       ADMINPASS 100.0000    MOBILE  JOHN SMITH  2014-11-01 17:50:57 2014-10-08  ADMIN   A456    SMITH & SMITH   251-345-6789    AL  36608   jsmith@smith.com
    f607a45d-71bb-4f73-ac49-858471ac67ae    NULL    NULL    PASS    NULL    NULL    NULL    2014-11-10 15:36:30 2014-11-10  ADMIN   TESTFIRM    TEST FIRM LLC   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
    9d8ec948-35e3-4daf-8523-feeec1252993    ADDRESS 1   ADDRESS 2   SOBPASS 83.3333 CITY    CONTACT 2014-11-01 14:21:26 2014-10-30  SOB A123    TEST FIRM NAME  123-456-7890    STATE   ZIP CODE    email@mydomain.com
```

So, I can get data with the exact SQL statement that EF sends to the server, but not inside of my app.

Comment: if `firms` is null `firms.ToList()` would throw NullReferenceException. Do you mean you know it's null via that exception? Setting a break point (before calling `ToList()`) should show that `firms` is a query (and it's obviously so - it should ***never*** be null).

Comment: `firms.ToList()` does throw NullReferenceException.

Comment: so as I said it's very strange, you obviously set `firms` to a query. It cannot be null. What possibly null is `fx` in `fx.FirmName`, so try filtering out all null `fx` to see it working: `from fx in db.FirmHdr where fx != null orderby fx.FirmName select fx;`. That's the only possible cause, although `db.FirmHdr` looks like an entity set (and then should not contain any null entity).

Comment: Still null. Here is part of the linq expression from firms if that helps: `.Call System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
        .Constant<Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryable`1[Asp5Test.Models.FirmHdr]>(Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryable`1[Asp5Test.Models.FirmHdr]),
        '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Asp5Test.Models.FirmHdr,System.Boolean]>)),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Asp5Test.Models.FirmHdr,System.String]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Asp5Test.Models.FirmHdr,System.Boolean]>(Asp5Test.Models.FirmHdr $fx) {
    $fx != null
}

Comment: you can set break point right before `firms.ToList()` is called to see what  `firms` is resolved to. I guess this looks like a bug in EF. Everything looks just fine and simple. Somehow the `NullReferenceException` is thrown ***internally*** (so it does not necessarily mean `firms` is null, which is very  strange). BTW, try checking the *InnerException* if any.

Comment: InnerException is null. I changed to EF Beta-6 and got this error on the query line: {"Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.TryAdd(Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor>)'."}

Answer (score 1):

Check that your table column types and your POCO class are matched. For example, if your column for *BaseAmt* can be null, the matching CLR type should be `decimal?` not `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on the money! I downgraded to EF6 and got a null error on the decimal field, so I corrected the model and all works now. Never got that message in EF7.

Here is the corrected model:

```
        public class FirmHdr
{
    [Key]
    public Guid GID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public string FirmCode { get; set; }
    public string FirmName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
    public decimal? BaseAmt { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string FirmAdmin { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
}
```